# Django not serving admin static files using fastcgi

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

I am trying to deploy my django app on a subdomain, say example.djangoapp.com, everything works fine, except for my django admin site, when i click on the link that goes to the admin site, it routes to a different url. This happens when i use the admin url template tag, i.e. it routes to djangoapp.com/index instead of example.djangoapp.index.fcgi/login (which is the admin site).

After removing the admin url template tag, i put an absolute url to the to redirect to the admin site, this work fine and the admin site shows up, but its static files are not served. So i am stack in between.

I am deploying on server that runs fastcgi on shared hosting

My questions:

1)Option 1 (Using the admin url template tag):

How do i get django to redirect me to the correct admin site (www.example.djangoapp.index.fcgi/login) instead of redirecting me to (www.djangoapp.com/index).

2) When using absolute url:
Now i hardcoded the admin link within my home template index page, this works fine but the django admin static files are not served. How can they get served?

Pardom my ignorance but i have been struggling with this for weeks. I decided to hardcode the url but still the admin sites static files are not being served.

Below is my settings.py , urls.py and index.html(where i hardcoded the admin site url). This code is inline with option 2 above that has the hardcoded admin site url.

settings.py

```
   WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cconnect_web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
}
}




# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Cairo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/cconnect/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home4/techaven/public_html/cconnect/static'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME="/index.fcgi/"
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cconnect_frontEnd import views
from . import settings
#app_name = 'cconnect_frontEnd

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name ='index'),
url(r'^backend/', include('Back_End.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',             {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]

urlpatterns += patterns('Back_End.views',
(r'^login/$', 'login_view'),
)

admin.site.site_header = 'Cconnect Administration.'
```

index.html

```
<body>

<div class="header-wrapper">

<nav>
<div class=nav-wrapper">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <img src="{% static "cconnect_frontEnd/images/slide/logo.png" %}" alt="Conference Connect"/>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    {% load admin_urls %}
        <li><a href="http://cconnect.techavenue137.rw/index.fcgi/admin">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#feature-title">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demo-video">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
```

index.fcgi

```
import os
import sys

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.insert(0, "/home4/techaven/public_html/cconnect/cconnect_web/")
os.chdir("/home4/techaven/public_html/cconnect/cconnect_web")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "cconnect_web.settings"

WSGIServer(get_wsgi_application()).run()
```

.htaccess

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
DirectoryIndex index.fcgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cconnect\.techavenue137\.rw$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cconnect\.techavenue137\.rw$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.techavenue137\.rw\/cconnect\/index\.fcgi" [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cconnect/
RewriteRule ^index\.fcgi$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cconnect/index.fcgi/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you for your help and once again pardon my stupid questions.

Comment: Your questions are not stupid. Firstly, I assume that you've collected the static files (`python manage.py collectstatic`) Secondly, is your webserver configured to serve the files? (eg Nginx should have a `location /cconect/static/` with the `alias` being your static root). What happens when you try it using the dev server? (`python manage.py runserver`) If it doesn't show, check the error message.

Comment: thank you keenan, yes my server is configured to serve the static files, on the dev server everything works just fine, the admin sites are served. on production server other static files are served only the admin site static files are not served. My thinking is that the error is in the url routing. And i do not know how to go about it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, the issue is with url routing. What is the error code when you inspect the elements that are missing? Is it 404, 403, 500? Also, could you post your webserver config for the app?

Comment: Keenan, Check my edited post, i posted the index.fcgi code and the .htaccess files. Note that i am using fastcgi on shared hosting. Also i am not using Nginx to serve the static files, they are served from the same server as the app. Thank you

Comment: When i use the inspect element i get the 500 internal error

Comment: Thank you for updating the post. The error 500 says that something is wrong with the internal server. Could you please post the error logs as well?

Comment: Keenan, I saw the error, it is in the static files url routing, the url of the admin static files passed by the browser is ....cconnect/static/admin/css/ and the admin site is located at .....index.fcgi/admin/login. The actual location of the admin site static files is index.fcgi/static/admin/css. How do i reset this, i am not sure how. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entirely fixed this issue by moving a different host, it was had to deploy and using fast cgi. I deployed to Digital Oceans and used Nginx to serve the static and media files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a rewrite rule to redirect the browser request to the actual static files for the admin page.
Below your last rewrite rule, add these lines:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" ".*/static/admin/.*"
RewriteRule "(.*)/cconect/(.*)" "$1/index.fcgi/$2" [R, L]
```

Here, the rewrite condition is saying that if the requested URI contains `/static/admin` then replace `cconnect` with `index.fcgi` and keep everything else the same. Mark it as a redirect [R] and stop rule processing if found [L]. I hope this solves your issue.

Disclaimer: I'm not very proficient in regex patterns and I have a basic understanding of Apache, so this solution might need to be tweaked. Have a look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) if you need to adjust it.

Comment: Hey Keenan, thank you for the support, but seems not to work, nothing changes. still acting as before

Comment: Hey Arnold. I'm sorry I couldn't help you to get it to work. Do you still have the same error?

Comment: Hey Keenan, am still facing the same error seems not to replace the cconnect with index.fcgi

Comment: Hi Arnold, I'm sorry it didn't work. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas. If you do find a solution, please answer your own question so that others may benefit from it.